# Mysql innoDB corruption after server crash

Tags: innodb, mysql

Yesterday my server died because an outage in the data center. Today it's back up, but having some problems with mysql.

First of all my mysql server was not able to start. For this reason I deleted the files **ib_logfile0** and **ib_logfile1** in /var/lib/mysql folder (**I still have the old failing files**).

After this my server was able to startup again. But now I see a lot of issues in the mysql log file.

```
Sep  1 09:43:55 * mysqld: 120901  9:43:55  InnoDB: Error: page 70944 log sequence number 8 1483471899
Sep  1 09:43:55 * mysqld: InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 5 612394935.
Sep  1 09:43:55 * mysqld: InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
Sep  1 09:43:55 * mysqld: InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
Sep  1 09:43:55 * mysqld: InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/forcing-recovery.html
```

When I check the docs on mysql.com, I found that I need to recover my database with backups. I have a backup but not sure what's the good way on importing it. Or is there a way to recover without having to re-import the database again?

So if I'm correct I need to put **innodb_force_recovery** to 4 in mysql and delete all current data and re-import? Is there a way to do this without having downtime?

I also have one slave running. This slave has the current status now:

> Last_Error: Relay log read failure: Could not parse relay log event
>   entry. The possible reasons are: the master's binary log is corrupted
>   (you can check this by running 'mysqlbinlog' on the binary log), the
>   slave's relay log is corrupted (you can check this by running
>   'mysqlbinlog' on the relay log), a network problem, or a bug in the
>   master's or slave's MySQL code. If you want to check the master's
>   binary log or slave's relay log, you will be able to know their names
>   by issuing 'SHOW SLAVE STATUS' on this slave.

How can I totally reset the slave after the new import on the master has happend?

Hopefully we can find a solution without not to much downtime.

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.softwareprojects.com/resources/programming/t-how-to-recover-from-mysql-replication-event-too-sma-1859.html

Comment: I restored an older DB dump. Now I can see less errors. But still a few every hour...

Comment: Here's an answer: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8011/any-better-way-out-of-mysql-innodb-log-in-the-future

Comment: "For this reason I deleted the files ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 in /var/lib/mysql folder"  <--- this is a mistake.  Restore the old files, then tell us what the real error is.  You're just creating new problems for yourself.